# Plot matrix with custom labels R

Tags: r, label, colorbar

I have to produce a plot using R and don't know how I can do it.
Imagine the following:

```
sample_names = c("a","b","d","e","f","g","h","i","l","m")
M = cbind(seq(0,1,length.out=10), c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
```

M is a 2 columns matrix where the first column is a continuous measurement,
and the second column is a label associated to the measurement (e.g. 1 is for "low", 2 is for "medium", 3 is for "high").

What I want to create is basically a vertical colorbar with labels both on the left and on the right. The colors should represent the values of the continuous measurements.
The labels on the left are the sample names, the labels on the right the corresponding
"low","medium", "high" labels for the data.

Possibly I would like the colors to range from green (0) to red (1) with dark colors around 0.5.

How can I possibly plot such a graph using R?

Comment: Take a look at: `filled.contour(z=matrix(1:10,10,2), nlevels=10)` and then look at the code used by `filled.contour` to draw its key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ggplot2`:

```
levels <- c('low','med','high')
df <- data.frame(
    sample = c("a","b","d","e","f","g","h","i","l","m"),
    value = seq(0,1,length.out=10),
    level = factor(levels[c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)], level=rev(levels))
)    

# require(ggplot2)
# require(grid)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=TRUE, y=sample, fill=value)) + geom_tile() +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c('green','black','red')) + 
facet_grid(level~., scales='free', space='free') +
scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
theme(panel.margin=unit(0.1,'mm'), axis.title=element_blank(), 
      axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
      legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: @LucaCerone, you're welcome. Just note that in your example, the alphabetical order of the samples corresponds to the increasing numerical value. This is unlikely in real situation, in which case `ggplot2` will treat the samples as factors and display them in the alphabetical order. To avoid this, it's best to first rank the samples based on their observed value and then preserve their order in the data frame with: `df$sample <- factor(df$sample, level=df$sample)`. In R, factor levels are always ordered alphabetically, unless specified differently via `level` argument.

Comment: I got exactly into this problem :)
Thanks a lot for the kind explanation!